# Resolution aware images not working - Flutter

Tags: android, image, flutter, devicepixelratio, flutter-assetimage

I am trying to add resolution aware image markers to google maps by converting each image to bitmap as such:

```dart
static Future<BitmapDescriptor> makeBitmapDescriptor(String path) {
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(), "assets/pinLocationIcons/house.png");
  }
```

I have followed this format [from flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#resolution-aware):

> .../pinLocationIcons/house.png
> .../pinLocationIcons/2.0x/house.png
> .../pinLocationIcons/3.0x/house.png
> ...etc.

It does not not seem to be working on both android and ios.
In my yaml file I have tried declaring only the ".../image.png" and also declaring each directory/file of the variants specifically. However, it continues to use the 1x image.

I tried naming the files like this instead:

> .../pinLocationIcons/house.png
> .../pinLocationIcons/house@2x.png
> .../pinLocationIcons/house@3x.png
> ...etc.

This now works for ios but always uses the 1x image for android.
Is there something I am missing that could make it work for both ios and android? Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some investigation it turns out I needed to declare device pixel ratio in the image configuration used to make the bitmap.

```dart
static Future<BitmapDescriptor> makeBitmapDescriptor(
      String path, BuildContext context) {
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
      ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio,
      path,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you find the asset path manually if you have a deadline for a project you are working on. Seems like you have done everything as per https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Answer (score 1):

Following up on [Shaveen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14872675/shaveen)'s answer you can also avoid having to use the `BuildContext` like so :

```dart
static Future<BitmapDescriptor> makeBitmapDescriptor(
      String path) {
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
      ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).devicePixelRatio,
      path,
    );
  }
```

using `MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).devicePixelRatio`